# How Insert 2 variable into ed command argument?

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, ed

I'm trying to do a while loop into bash script but I don't know what's going on with the ed (text editor) when I tried to insert a varible in its arguments. As you can see, I'm using a loop as well, but the problem seem to be in the use of varibles inside ed command.

Here is the script code (obvious the awk and sed programs):

```
#!/bin/bash

x=1
y=5

SCRIPTDIR=~/bin

awk 'NR % 2==0' test > output1
awk -v n=5 '1; NR % n == 0 {print ""}' output1 > output1b
sed -i 's/\r//' output1b

while [ $x -le 50 ]; do
    ed -s output1b <<< $"$xm$y\nw"
let x=x+5
let y=y+5
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ed -s output1b <<< $"$xm$y\nw"
```

should be

```
ed -s output1b <<ED_COMMANDS
${x}m$y
w
ED_COMMANDS
```

or

```
printf "%s\n" "${x}m$y" "w" | ed -s output1b
```

The `$"..."` form won't translate `\n` to a newline, and the `$'...'` form won't expand variables.

Also, note the braces in `${x}m$y` otherwise the shell is looking for variables `$xm` and `$y`

Comment: Thank you very much Glenn, the second option was good for me. I should study the bash manual (quotes, especial characters....) but I'm starting.

Comment: It's good to read the section on [quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting) and [redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) (applicable here), and familiarize yourself with the order of [shell expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions)

Comment: @glennjackman I've been looking this for more than 5 hours, thank you so much!